# How to dynammically create layout elements for each collection in my Firestore on my android app?

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

I'm creating an android app connected to firestore and firebase auth. So basicly the app let's users sign up and create a profile with name, address, age, etc. That data will be stored into firestore and I want the app to show the list of each user that signed up.

What I'm wondering is if there's a way to display a button (or any other layout element) for each user that signed up?

I'm sorry I haven't tried anything yet because I don't know what to look for as I'm pretty new to android.

thanks.

Comment: Is signed up or is logged in (is online)?

Comment: signed up. so for each collection created by a user into firestore, i want to make a button show up in my app

Comment: So you have a collection of users, right? Have you tried to display them in a `ListView` or even better in a `RecyclerView`?